# How to write data from a TableView to the pdf?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, itext

I tried a lot and got itext pdf code below. However I want to write data from a [`TableView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html) to the pdf. How can this be achieved ?

```
  public class Pdf2 {
    public static final String RESULT
        = "c:/temp/FirstPdf.pdf";

    /**
     * Main method.
     * @param    args    no arguments needed
     * @throws DocumentException 
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException, DocumentException {
        new Pdf2().createPdf(RESULT);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a PDF with information about the movies
     * @param    filename the name of the PDF file that will be created.
     * @throws    DocumentException 
     * @throws    IOException
     */
    public void createPdf(String filename)
        throws IOException, DocumentException {
        // step 1
        Document document = new Document();
        // step 2
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
        // step 3
        document.open();
        // step 4
        document.add(createFirstTable());
        // step 5
        document.close();
    }

    /**
     * Creates our first table
     * @return our first table
     */
    public static PdfPTable createFirstTable() {
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5);

    PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("QTY"));
    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    table.addCell(c1);

    c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Item"));
    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    table.addCell(c1);

    c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Description"));
    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    table.addCell(c1);
     c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Unit Price"));
    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    table.addCell(c1);
    c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Total"));
    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    table.addCell(c1);
    table.setHeaderRows(1);

    table.addCell("1");
    table.addCell("2");
    table.addCell("3");
     table.addCell("4");
    table.addCell("5");


        return table;
    }
}
```

This code above is itext pdf in java. Can I create a PDF with data from a javafx table inserted? Is there any other way to build pdf using JavaFX application?

Comment: @fabian create pdf from a javafx application and to show the pdf at same time.

Comment: @fabian exactly filling a javafx table with data and writing that data into pdf is the sharp i needed.Please Help Me!

Comment: TableView just shows data from an ObersvableList<T>. You can just fetch the same list from the tableview by firing `getItems()` on it and implement a method which creates a PDF from the data. It is pretty straight forward but may be a broad question for this forum. Try this out, and if you get stuck somewhere, ask another question.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha i have a tableview with datas in it using ObservableList<T> as you mentioned above.I am Stuck at how to create pdf Table with datas in the Tableview and preview Pdf at same time.Should I ask another question? If yes Please help me with an appropriate question that will strike on users who have answers.

Comment: You can try using [Jasper Reports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library) or [Dynamic Reports](http://www.dynamicreports.org/) which makes creating tables in PDF easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **itext pdf** you can create pdf in javafx.Here is the sample code that write database values into pdf table cell.You can use the same sql query that writes data to the tableview in javafx.Download itextpdf and sqlconnector jar files.

```
 @FXML
       private void pdfs() 
          throws Exception{
        try {
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
               Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login", "root", "");
  Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                    /* Define the SQL query */
                    ResultSet query_set = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT *From tablename");
                    /* Step-2: Initialize PDF documents - logical objects */
                    Document my_pdf_report = new Document();
                    PdfWriter.getInstance(my_pdf_report, new FileOutputStream("pdf_report_from_sql_using_java.pdf"));
                    my_pdf_report.open();            
                    //we have four columns in our table
                    PdfPTable my_report_table = new PdfPTable(4);
                    //create a cell object
                    PdfPCell table_cell;

                    while (query_set.next()) {                
                                    String dept_id = query_set.getString("code");
                                    table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dept_id));
                                    my_report_table.addCell(table_cell);
                                    String dept_name=query_set.getString("category");
                                    table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dept_name));
                                    my_report_table.addCell(table_cell);
                                    String manager_id=query_set.getString("total");
                                    table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(manager_id));
                                    my_report_table.addCell(table_cell);
                                    String location_id=query_set.getString("Sum");
                                    table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(location_id));
                                    my_report_table.addCell(table_cell);
                                    }
                    /* Attach report table to PDF */
                    my_pdf_report.add(my_report_table);                       
                    my_pdf_report.close();

                    /* Close all DB related objects */
                    query_set.close();
                    stmt.close(); 
                    con.close();               



    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

i think this will help you !any doubts comment.